# How do I go from Labor Statistics results to generalities on the population?

Tags: survey

I'm currently looking at survey results from the US bureau of labor statistics concerning hourly wages. With the raw survey data, I get different respondents who state how many hours they work in a week, along with the average pay, and some demographic data like age and sex.

How can I go from this information to making an educated guess about the amount of hours have been worked by the entire US population at a certain wage level, for example? Is there some way to "correlate" the values considering more than just a single parameter like age?

EDIT: I'm going to try and ask a more specific question then. Please forgive my complete lack of statistics knowledge:

Let's say I'm doing a survey about how much people earn in an hour. Based off of my survey, I know that , in my survey sample, men make about \$10 an hour, and women make \$8 an hour.  I also know that in the same sample, people under 40 make \$7 an hour on average, and people over 40 make \$11 an hour.

Assuming that the population is 50/50 male/female, I can make an educated guess that the population , on average, makes \$9 an hour. Likewise, if %30 of the population is over 40, then I can guess that the population on average makes \$8.20 an hours

But how can I "combine" both of these information points? How can I consider both the sex and the age of the people to fit it to the population? Am I just supposed to do a weighted average or something?

Comment: It is difficult to imagine a useful concise answer to this. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask including the advice "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."

Comment: ok, I tried to edit my question to be more specific. I fear that it might still be too general.

Comment: just use any survey that generalizes to the whole population instead of the working population.. you probably want the bls current population survey.  to work with the microdata, [start here](http://asdfree.com)

Comment: @Anthony: but, CPS generalizes to the `working age` population not the whole US population; the survey focuses on the civilian noninstitutional population 16 years and over.

Comment: @metrics that is not correct. [this page](http://aspe.hhs.gov/hsp/06/catalog-ai-an-na/cps.htm) says, "the civilian noninstitutional population"  kids don't get the employment questions, but there are child records - with nonzero weights.  it's a household survey :)  if you don't believe me, sum up the person-weights -- you'll get ~310 million not ~230 million

Comment: I see. I thought there are no child records. Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

To generalize the results from survey data for the population, you need sample weights. If you are using the microdata/survey data from BLS, you can find the weights in the data. Of course, you have to look into codebook or data dictionary if you can't locate. See [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=why%20use%20weights%20in%20survey&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://help.pop.psu.edu/help-by-statistical-method/weighting/Introduction%2520to%2520survey%2520weights%2520pri%2520version.ppt&ei=J1vZUZ-OH9KTqwH01YHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNGRb2ouJZWMTgtIED3Y1TWll3ZDGA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWM) introduction slides.

For analysis purpose you need to use survey analysis tool which is [this](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) in R and [this](http://www.stata.com/features/survey-commands/) is Stata